# Temperature Dependence of Thermal Efficiency in Carnot Cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

Suppose a Carnot Cycle operates between a hot reservoir at temp $T_h$ and a cold reservoir at temp $T_c$. Suppose also that the system is initially at point $(V_1,p_1)$ in the pV-plane and that the subsequent states of the system in the pV-plane are $(V_2,p_2)$, $(V_3,p_3)$ and $(V_4,p_4)$, respectively. Finally, suppose also that the heat absorbed by the system during isothermal expansion is $Q_{12}$ and that the heat surrendered to the cold reservoir during isothermal compression is $Q_{43}$. Then, the thermal efficiency of the cycle is given by

\begin{equation}
\eta = 1 - \frac{Q_{43}}{Q_{12}}  = 1 - \frac{T_c}{T_h} \quad (1)
\end{equation}

However, by the Ideal Gas Law, the above can be written as

$$ \eta = 1 - \frac{T_c\cdot \ln(V_3/V_4)}{T_h\cdot \ln(V_2/V_1)} $$

Now, for the second equality in (1) to hold, it must be the case that
$V_3/V_4 = V_2/V_1$. How do I know apriori that this is true? There's no obvious reason I can discern that the above statement would necessarily be true.

Comment: This is where we need it to be in a cycle. There are more relations. In essence, the relationship needed just means that the number of molecules in the gas is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Write your result as
$$
   \eta 
   = 1 - \frac{T_c \Delta S_{34}}{T_h\Delta S_{21}}
$$
and recall that the Carnot cycle is reversible, so that  $\Delta S_{12}+\Delta S_{34}=0$, which gives the correct efficiency.

This answers your question *indirectly*  (and not only for ideal gas): Since your equation *is* correct, you ought to be able to *prove* it. Fix enough information to calculate the pressure and volume in all states, then show the relationship between the volumes. Or follow the hint in the comment by @naturallyInconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to equate the volumes through their laws in the cicle, two isothermal (1-2 & 3-4) and two adiabatic curves (2-3 & 4-1).
In the first you have
(i) $p_1V_1 = p_2V_2$
(iii) $p_3 V_3 = p_4 V_4$
Then for the adiabatic curves,
(ii) $p_2 V_2^\alpha = p_4 V_4^\alpha$
(iv) $p_2 V_2^\alpha = p_4 V_4^\alpha$
in which $\alpha$ depends on the gas.

Now, working with eqs. (i) to (iv) you can demonstrate that your (1) is the same as your second equation, that is $V_3/V_4=V_2/V_1$.